# How can I detect missed SysEx data in MidiInProc?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, callback, midi

I am writing a program in C# under Windows 10 to capture SysEx messages from MIDI devices. I'm using a callback function as follows:

```c#
    private delegate void MidiInProc(
        int handle,
        uint msg,
        int instance,
        int param1,
        int param2);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern int midiInOpen(
        out int handle,
        int deviceID,
        MidiInProc proc,
        int instance,
        int flags);

    private int hHandle;

    public MidiInput(int deviceID)
    {
        MidiInProc midiInProc = MidiInProcess;

        int hResult = midiInOpen(
            out hHandle,
            deviceID,
            midiInProc,
            0,
            CALLBACK_FUNCTION | MIDI_IO_STATUS);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MIDIHDRS; ++i)
        {
            InitMidiHdr(i);
        }
    }

    private void MidiInProcess(int hMidiIn, uint uMsg, int dwInstance, int dwParam1, int dwParam2)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
            case MIM_OPEN:

                break;

            case MIM_CLOSE:

                break;

            case MIM_DATA:

                QueueData(dwParam1);

                break;

            case MIM_MOREDATA:

                QueueData(dwParam1);

                break;

            case MIM_LONGDATA:

                QueueLongData((IntPtr)dwParam1);

                break;

            case MIM_ERROR:

                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Invalid MIDI message: {0}", dwParam1));

            case MIM_LONGERROR:

                throw new ApplicationException("Invalid SysEx message.");

            default:

                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("unexpected message: {0}", uMsg));
        }
    }
```

The `InitMidiHdr` method creates `NUM_MIDIHDRS` headers and buffers on the heap and passes their addresses to the driver with calls to `MidiInPrepareHeader` and `MidiInAddBuffer`. When SysEx data is received, the callback switches to the `MIM_LONGDATA` case and queues the buffer address to another thread which dequeues it, processes it, and then passes it back to the driver for further use via another call to `MidiInAddBuffer`.

Now, some programs do not use a separate thread, instead processing SysEx data on the callback's thread. From what I have read, this works most of the time, but not always, and is against the [MSDN's advice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798460(v=vs.85).aspx): "Applications should not call any multimedia functions from inside the callback function[.]" This may not be a problem with contemporary drivers, but some users have, in the past, reported deadlocks when calling `MidiInAddBuffer` directly from the callback.

But...

When I use a worker thread to call `MidiInAddBuffer`, I can't think of a way to guarantee that it will keep up with calls to the callback. Sure, if the *only* thing the worker does is return the buffer, it will probably stay ahead of the callback, but relying on one thread to stay ahead of another without explicit synchronization is a bad practice. (Having the callback wait on a signal from the worker that it has returned the buffer doesn't work, as `MidiInAddBuffer` blocks when called from another thread until the callback returns, which leads to a deadlock if you condition its return on a return from `MidiInAddBuffer` in the worker thread.) Thus, it's possible in that scenario for the driver to run out of buffers while the MIDI device is still sending SysEx data. (Indeed, even in the scenario where the callback does all the processing itself, it too might fall behind, with the driver using up all of its buffers before the device stops sending SysEx data.)

I have found a couple of open-source projects that use a worker to call `MidiInAddBuffer`, but both appear to rely on the worker to stay ahead of calls to the callback. In fact, in one case, I added a 50ms sleep call to the worker, with the result being that it fell far behind the callback thread, which ultimately meant that only about half of the SysEx messages made it to the callback. Apparently, the driver doesn't buffer SysEx data internally and, when it has no buffers left to use, throws SysEx data away until it gets another buffer.

Now, memory being cheap and all that, one "solution" is to have a *lot* of buffers. My Behringer BCF2000, however, sends almost *500* distinct SysEx messages in a single dump, each in its own buffer. That's not an impossible number to supply, but it requires guesswork as to how many is really enough (and, given some of the exotic things people use SysEx messages to do, like pass around audio samples, such an approach could get unwieldy).

Alas, the `MIM_LONGERROR` case never gets called when my tests show that my code isn't keeping up, so that's no help.

So, here's my question: If my code is unable to keep up with the rate at which SysEx buffers are consumed by a MIDI device's driver and I end up missing some SysEx data, is there any way to at least detect that I have missed that data?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reporting mechanism for missed SysEx buffers.

At the MIDI speed of 3125 bytes/s, the 50 ms delay corresponds to a buffer of 156 bytes; if the actual messages are shorter, you are guaranteed to fall behind.
But real code will not have such a consistent delay, so this is not a realistic test. Your threads might get random scheduling delays, but this is no problem as long as you have enough buffers queued. (And if some other code with higher priority prevents your code from being executed at all, there's nothing you can do anyway.)

Comment: What is the reporting mechanism for missed SysEx buffers?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Those MIDI speeds apply when using actual MIDI hardware. The equipment I'm using is USB, which runs a lot faster. But 50ms wouldn't be a rare delay if, say, the SysEx data were being sent across a network. Or, more simply, if the worker thread blocked on user input. Regardless, it's not the delay that concerns me, but the inability of the worker to know if it has missed a message. One approach would be track the buffer count, decrementing on each call to the worker, incrementing on each return. If the count reaches zero, you're probably missing messages after that.